back() method in Karate UI testing is taking more than 30 seconds to complete
Feature: Browser Navigation Methods

  Scenario: back(), forward()
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome' }
    * driver 'https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/'
    * maximize()
    * print "title is:",driver.title
    * delay(2000)
    * driver 'https://www.saucedemo.com/'
    * print "title is:",driver.title
    * delay(2000)
    * back()
    * print "title is:",driver.title
    * delay(2000)
    * forward()
    * print "title is:",driver.title
    * delay(2000)


Tried with multiple website urls. I have attached the code snippet and html report. I am trying to navigate back and forward. Karate 1.4.1 version.

yes, sounds like the chrome message does not result in a response and there is this 30 second timeout. feel free to raise an issue, and do consider investigating and submitting a PR
